# GCC/G++ different attitudes for: void* to int

Tags: c++, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void test(void *arg)
{
    if (arg != NULL)
    {
        int temp = (int *)arg;
        printf("[temp]%d\n", temp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    int *b = &a;
    int t = b;
    test((void *)11);
    void * arg = (void *)22;
    int k = (int *)arg;//this statement  can not compaile  with G++,But GCC only Warning,why?（evernt use cpp rewrite it again）
    // int k=*(int *)arg;// why this statement not right?
    printf("[k]%d\n", k);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages.  Don't expect what works in one to work in the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int k = (int *)arg;
> ```
>
> this statement  can not compaile  with G++,But GCC only Warning,why?

It doesn't compile in C++ because `int*` is not implicitly convertible to `int` and therefore the statement is ill-formed.

> ```
> // int k=*(int *)arg;
> ```
>
> why this statement not right?

That statement is syntactically well-formed in C++. But `arg` doesn't point to an `int` object (or object of compatible type), so the behaviour of indirecting through the pointer is undefined.